# Can Iblis submit to Allah?

Tags: shaitan, jinn

[This question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9117/why-does-iblees-and-shaytaans-disobey-allah) got me thinking: If Iblis has free will, as all jinn do, it would stand to reason that he is capable of realizing the errors of his ways and praying to Allah, regardless of whether Allah would accept him back. However, I have never seen or heard anything suggesting that Iblis is capable of calming his pride and anger. Does Iblis have the capacity to change? In 7:14-15, Iblis requests reprieve and is granted it. Even if Allah has no intention of taking Iblis back, is it possible that he is left to his own actions in order to give him time to see the error of his ways?

Comment: Well, theoretically it is possible and God, in His infinite mercy can forgive him for all the sins he has committed.

Comment: in theory yes... don't how authentic the story about Musa (A.S.) and Iblis is but read for yourself: http://www.al-islam.org/anecdotes-reflection-part-3/13.htm

Comment: Before actual taubah, the taufique for doing taubah comes from Allah. Allah holds the hearts of all His servants between His Fingers and turns them where He wants. After the enormous number of problems that Shaitaan has created for us humans as well as believing jinns during humanity's entire existence, including doing his best to dispatch them to the Fire of Hell, do you think Allah will incline his heart towards taubah? (And none can coerce Allah; He does as He pleases and none can question Him.)

Comment: in history, it was happened when iblis asked prophet Muhammad about 'taubah', then prophet asked Iblis to sujud to Adam but he still reject it.. I think [it never gonna be happened even if possible](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9148/can-iblis-submit-to-allah)

Answer (score 1):

Allah (swt) is The merciful.

Iblis asked Musa (pbuh) that can you ask Allah (swt) if there is forgiveness for him. Allah (swt) said yes if Iblis does the prostration to Adam (pbuh) at Adam's (pbuh) grave.

When Musa informed this to Iblis. Iblis became very angry and said did not prostrate to Adam (pbuh) when He was alive, do you think I will do that now that He is dead.

So the door of forgiveness is open for Iblis but Iblis chooses to be arrogant.

Comment: Salam and Welcome to Islam.SE, we recommend you check out our [help].  We ask that you add a source/citation to your answer to make it stronger, as it stands it is kind of low quality, and it's source is not provided.

Answer (score 0):

I can remember that someone said (as a tradition) that Allah gives the opportunity to Satan to repent, but Satan in spite of knowing about his wrong act, but does not accept it because of his pride.

Answer (score -1):

Allah is all knowing..  Do not compare Allah's knowledge with the kind he bestowed to us..  So Allah knows clearly that Iblis is not going to come back to right path..

Same is the case when Allah said in Quran that Allah has created among human people destined to hell..

Answer (score -1):

First let me correct you by saying that Iblis/Devils <> Jinn. Shaitan is a Jinn but a Jinn is not necessary Shitan. Shitan is a given name to those Jinn who disbelieve in Allah.

To answer your question, Iblis was an Jinn Angle (many scholars would differ but it is clearly stated in the Quran) that refused to obey Allah's order because of his Pride and was thrown out of Heaven. Iblis's pride is so deep that he asked Allah to give him time till the end of Judgment to lead astray that kind that he was asked to prostrate to.

Allah can do anything, he can even erase us all from memory after the day of Judgment so he choose to. However, we believe that he promised us Heaven and promised Iblis and his followers hell.

Comment: Please post reference for your claim "Iblis was an Jinn Angle". Though a lot of people have said the same but I have never seen it in Quran if you could provide reference, it would be great.